# See if a value exists in NSDictionary key/value pairs that are elements of NSMutableArray in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I did some searching but could not find a definitive answer for this question.  I apologize, I am a java developer who knows nothing about Swift, this is my first post ever on StackExchange, and of course I have been tasked with trying to learn swift in 24 hours on a project with tight deadlines.  You know the drill - Good Times!  :-)

An NSMutableArray called lotNumberArray is being assigned key/value pairs from a JSON response object into array elements that I believe are NSDictionary objects containing key/value pairs for the keys LOT_NO and MOD_SEQ as shown by the output of the print() statement below the following code block.

I would like to loop through lotNumberArray which contains elements of NSDictionary (key/value pairs), and determine if the key **LOT_NO = All** for any of the elements, and return a true boolean value for this test.  Could you please suggest how I might code this?  I believe the project is using Swift 4.

```
lotNumberArray = response["data"] as! NSMutableArray

for item in lotNumberArray {

        print("Found \(item)")

        // need code here which returns 
        // boolean true value if "LOT_NO = All" is in any of the NSDictionary elements
        // of the NSMutableArray lotNumberArray 
                       
}
```

output from print() above:

> Found {
>
> ```
> "LOT_NO" = 7203;
> "MOD_SEQ" = 1279108; }
> ```
>
> Found {
>
> ```
> "LOT_NO" = All;
> "MOD_SEQ" = 944877; }
> ```
>
> Found {
>
> ```
> "LOT_NO" = 923;
> "MOD_SEQ" = 128366; }
> ```

Comment: thank you for your help formatting this Vadian!     I am really struggling with my first time here  :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all. By the way you'll never get a mutable array in coercion.

The Swift way is

```
lotNumberArray = response["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
let found = lotNumberArray.first{$0["LOT_NO"] as? String == "All"} != nil
```

The `first` statement searches for the first occurrence of the predicate

Comment: Thank you Vadian, I tried your suggestion and am now receiving the following error:      Value of type 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscripts

Comment: Where does the error occur? That's the disadvantage of `NSArray`. It's typeless. Use always Swift native types.

Answer (score 0):

```
lotNumberArray = response["data"] as! NSMutableArray

for item in lotNumberArray {

        print("Found \(item)")
        if let itemAsDict = item as? NSDictionary {
            if let value = itemAsDict.objectFor(key:"LOT_NO") as? String {
                if( value == "All" ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
             
}
return false
```